# Query Optimization - To repeat a pattern in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Introduction: I can do this in MS-Excel, it takes me 1 minute, but I m trying to get this in Oracle SQL

Here is my Code:

```
SELECT A.*, (CASE WHEN A.r = 1 then 'X1' when A.r = 2 then 'X2' when A.r = 3 then 'X3' when A.r = 4 
then 'X4' when A.r = 5 then 'X2' when A.r = 6 then 'X6' end) X FROM
(
    Select Rownum r
    From dual
    Connect By Rownum <= 6 ) A
```

This is the Output:

[image]

Now, what if I have to do it for 25000 numbers, meaning when (rownum <= 25000) currently I have it only for 6, Is there a better method to do this with out case statement?

Comment: I'll reply in some time, I m going to buy some food.

Comment: What is the rule?

Comment: Since you need convert 5 to `X2` is is not obvious how to extrapolate this to 25000 items. If 5 goes to `X5` it can be simple concatenation. Please, describe the rule to transform number to X.

Comment: @GordonLinoff So the rule is to get the pattern, If the column has a value, for example 2431, I want to get the output as X2431.

Comment: @astentx Sorry, Fixed the Image,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to repeat this pattern of 6 rows for the remaining rows, then you can do:

```
select t.*, 
       (case when mod(rownum, 6) = 5 then 'X2'
             else 'X' || (mod(rownum - 1, 6) + 1)
        end)
from t;
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff, I modified the image, there was an error in the image, I ll try doing this without the case statement. It Works